# Ubuntu 16.10 internal error - Compiz crash

Tags: compiz, freeze, crash

I am getting this error (see image) again and again, and can't find a solution. This was just one of many times and Ubuntu froze many times also.

[image]

Comment: have a check if possible to edit some parts of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple crash events too.

I run this:

gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1

I got this idea from this URL:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939312

Hope it helps you too!